# How are random access iterators for non-contiguous containers (such as std::deque) implemented?

Tags: c++, iterator, deque, random-access

I understand how random access iterators work for contiguous containers like `std::vector`: the iterator simply maintains a pointer to the current element and any additions/subtractions are applied to the pointer.

However, I'm baffled as to how similar functionality could be implemented for a non-contiguous container. My first guess for how `std::deque:iterator` works, is that it maintains a pointer to some table of the groups of contiguous memory it contains, but I'm not sure.

How would a typical standard library implement this?

Comment: Who says a `deque` isn't contiguous? It's usually implemented as a dynamic array.

Comment: @ooga from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) `As opposed to std::vector, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.`

Comment: @ooga, Then how would it differ from a vector?

Comment: @BryanChen I wonder what that means? A "sequence ... of arrays"?

Comment: A diagram for a typical `deque`: http://kremer.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/STL/1024x768/deque.html  and an article that looks like it might be helpful (though I've only glanced at it): https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/deques/page/deques.html

Comment: kind of `std::list<std::array<T>>`. i.e. linked list of arrays

Comment: @Bryan or like a hash table that has pointers to other tables instead of linked lists.

Comment: @MichaelBurr So it has a kind of contiguity. I.e., you can fairly-efficiently randomly access elements. I guess it trys to keep as many contiguous elements as possible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's somewhat like I imagined. So would each iterator hold a reference to `deque`'s map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can satisfy the requirememts of a `std::deque` with a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::array<T,N>>>` roughly. plus a low/high water mark telling you where the first/last elements are. (for an implementation defined N that could vary with `T`, and the `std::array`s are actually blocks of properly aligned uninitialized memory and not `std::array`s, but you get the idea).

Use usual exponential growth, but on both front and back.

Lookup simply does `(index+first)/N` and `%N` to find the block and sub element.

This is more expensive than a `std::vector` lookup, but is O(1).

Comment: At [http://cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) the page for deque::push_back indicate constant time complexity while the page for vector::push_back indicated amortized constant time complexity. Wouldn't using a vector as a backend for pointers to arrays violate the requirement that deque::push_back be constant? Or is amortized constant acceptable?

Comment: @mebob elsewhere it states amortized constant: is error.  I should fix it after confirming with the standard.

Comment: OK that makes sense. I can't really think of a way to get around the amortized constant limit anyway.

And back to my question about iterators: so an iterator would simply hold a reference to the said vector and switch buffers when it reached the end of one?

Comment: @mebob yes, something like that.

Comment: You might also want to add that making `N` a compile-time constant that's also a power of two (a `static_assert`, perhaps) should be very good for performance.

Answer (score 3):

A deque iterator can be implemented by storing both a pointer to the referenced value and a double pointer to the contiguous block of memory in which that value is located. The double pointer points into a contiguous array of pointers to blocks managed by the deque.

```
class deque_iterator
{
  T* value;
  T** block;
  …
}
```

Because both `value` and `block` point into contiguous memory, you can implement operations such finding the distance between iterators in constant time (example adapted from libc++).

```
difference_type operator-(deque_iterator const& x, deque_iterator const& y)
{
  return (x.block - y.block) * block_size
       + (x.value - *x.block)
       - (y.value - *y.block);
}
```

Note that, while `value` will not be invalidated by operations such as `push_front` and `push_back`, `block` might be, which is why `deque_iterator` is invalidated by such operations.

Comment: Thats the only answer that answers the question so far,  and definitely a good one.